# Using DOMDocument & loadHTML in PHP to find out the class of a tag

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to get all LI tags that are inside OL tags which have the "bananas" class, so for example if the HTML looks like:

```
<ol class="pluots plums grapes">
    <li>back to the future 2</li>
    <li>lemon bars</li>
</ol>

<ol class="walnuts bananas cornbread">
    <li>mustard</li>
    <li>ketchup</li>
</ol>
```

I want to be able to get mustard & ketchup only.

So this here:

```
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$ols = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ol');
  foreach ($ols as $ol) {
     echo "<br/>". $ol->nodeName. ": ";
     $nodes = $ol->childNodes;
     foreach ($nodes as $node) {
          echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
}
```

will get me all of the LI's but I want to get only the ones from the OL that has "bananas" class?

I can get the class names kind of clumsily by doing this:

```
foreach ($ol->attributes as $attr) {
    $value = $attr->nodeValue;
}
```

I just want to be able to call the class for an OL so I figured it would be something like:

```
$class=$ol->attributes->[????]->nodeValue to get the class but I can't seem to figure it out.
```

I need to be able to select by class because sometimes these OLs will be in different order.

Comment: Did you try getElementById?

Comment: I'm not looking for the ID, I'm looking for the class.

Comment: sorry, try this...  document.getElementsByClassName('walnuts bananas cornbread')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping through them, check the value of the `class` attribute to see if it contains `bananas`.

```
<?
$html = <<<HTML
<ol class="pluots plums grapes">
    <li>back to the future 2</li>
    <li>lemon bars</li>
</ol>

<ol class="walnuts bananas cornbread">
    <li>mustard</li>
    <li>ketchup</li>
</ol>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$ols = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ol');

foreach ($ols as $ol) {
    $classes = $ol->getAttribute('class');

    if (strpos($classes, 'bananas') !== false) {
        $nodes = $ol->getElementsByTagName('li');

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
              echo trim($node->nodeValue)."\n";
        }   
    }   
}
```

This prints out:

```
mustard
ketchup
```

As for your second question, the [MDN HTML Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Reference) as well as the [MDN DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) are both really complete.

Comment: These OLs will not always be in the same order, that's why I need to search by class.